# incompatible pointer to integer conversion strchr

Tags: c, char, c-strings, counting, function-definition

sorry if this question has already been asked here, I didn't find answer, so I'm trying to do a programme for count somme lettre in text, here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// ƒ to count the lettre E
void lettreCount(char *saisi, int length){
    int i, count = 0;

    for (i = 0; i  < length; i++){  //loop for find and count lettre
    
        if (strchr(&saisi[i],"e")){  //verification of lettre
            ++i;
            count++;
        }
    } 

    printf("Dans votre text il y a %d de lettre \"e\"\n", count);
}


int main(){
    char text[132]; //Array for text
    int len;

    printf("Saisissez le text:\n");
    gets(text);

    len = strlen(text);

    lettreCount(text, len);
    
}
```

but i get all time this warning:

```
incompatible pointer to integer conversion passing 'char [2]' to parameter of type 'int' [-Wint-conversion]
                if (strchr(&saisi[i],"e")){  //verification of lettre
                                     ^~~
```

what do i do wrong?

Comment: `"e"` should be `'e'`. It gets the character itself, not a string.

Comment: Just to clarify a bit, the `"e"` argument will pass to `strchr` a _pointer_ (value of type `char*`) to the memory location where the `"e"` string is stored, while the `'e'` will pass the character itself (value of type `char`).

Answer (score 0):

The function `strchr` expects as its second argument an object of the type `int`.

```
char *strchr(const char *s, int c);
```

However you supplied a string literal that is implicitly converted to the type `char *`.

```
if (strchr(&saisi[i],"e"))
```

You should write at least like

```
strchr(&saisi[i], 'e' )
```

Also pay attention to that the function expects that the first argument contains a string.

So this function declaration

```
void lettreCount(char *saisi, int length){
```

within which there is used the standard string function `strchr` does not make a sense.

Also this for loop

```
for (i = 0; i  < length; i++){  //loop for find and count lettre

    if (strchr(&saisi[i],"e")){  //verification of lettre
        ++i;
        count++;
    }
}
```

also does not make a sense and has bugs. For example if to update the call of `strchr` the same character `'e'` can be counted several times or some letters in the string can be skipped from counting.

The function can be declared and defined the following way

```
size_t lettreCount( const char *s, int c )
{
    size_t n = 0;

    for ( ; ( s = strchr( s, c ) ) != NULL; ++s )
    {
        ++n;
    }
   
    return n;
}
```

And in main the function can be called like

```
printf( "Dans votre text il y a %zu de lettre \"e\"\n", lettreCount( text, 'e' ) );
```

If to declare the function with the parameter that specifies the size of the character array then the function can be declared and defined the following way

```
size_t lettreCount( const char *s, size_t n, int c )
{
    size_t count = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        if ( s[i] == c ) ++count;
    }
   
    return count;
}
```

Also bear in mind the that function `gets` is unsafe and is not supported by the C Standard. Instead use the function `fgets`.